# UI.tabs with Superfish menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery.ui.tabs to create a carousel. On the same page is a superfish dropdown menu. Everytime I'm hovering over a menu item and the tabs switch, the menu closes if it's a submenu or flickers if it's a top-level menu.

See http://demos.zatechcorp.com/mm/ for an example. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
#global-nav ul.sub {
z-index: 9999;
}
#global-nav ul.products {
z-index: 9999;
}
```

That will give the dropdown lists the highest z-index on the page, and the transitions won't interfere with them anymore. Tested with Firebug and it seems to solve any flickering.